# comparing strings between 2 arrays

Tags: powershell

I have 2 arrays like below.I only need those elements in $b whose names are not present in $a.As it can be seen,element names on $a and $b are not same.$b has full name whereas $a has only a part of the name.

```
$a="rohit","shikar","virat","ravindra"
$b="rohit : sharma","shikar : dhawan","virat : kohli","ajinx : rahane","ravi : ashwin"
```

I've tried to loop through $b and use operators like -contain,-match,-like but those do not work.

Comment: Please do not double post. You asked practically the same question yesterday and got some good answers.

Comment: Sorry about that.I only consumed the answer (using the -contains operator)from my earlier question.In that sense,this one appeared a different case to me as those operators do not work in this example.Thanks to all those who helped me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using a regex:

```
$a="rohit","shikar","virat","ravindra"
$b="rohit : sharma","shikar : dhawan","virat : kohli","ajinx : rahane","ravi : ashwin"

$a_regex = ‘(?i)(‘ + (($a |foreach {[regex]::escape($_)}) –join “|”) + ‘)’

$b -notmatch $a_regex

ajinx : rahane
ravi : ashwin
```

If you know there aren't going to be an regex metacharacters in $a that might need to be escaped, it can be as simple as:

```
$a="rohit","shikar","virat","ravindra"
$b="rohit : sharma","shikar : dhawan","virat : kohli","ajinx : rahane","ravi : ashwin"

$a_regex = $a -join '|'

$b -notmatch $a_regex

ajinx : rahane
ravi : ashwin
```